# Facebook PlacePicker removed, which one to replace it?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

The change log: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x

It said that Picker fragments - Have been removed.
So, I wonder what is the replacement for it?